# how to write a locator and select a dropdown value

Tags: java, selenium

I've tried below code :

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'--None--')]")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

Getting below error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element
>   should have been "select" but was "a"

This is my full DOM structure :

```
<div class="compoundTLRadius compoundTRRadius compoundBorderBottom form-element__row uiMenu" data-aura-rendered-by="2600:0" data-aura-class="uiMenu">
   <div id="2574:0" data-aura-rendered-by="2581:0" class="uiPopupTrigger" data-aura-class="uiPopupTrigger" data-interactive-uid="19">
      <div data-aura-rendered-by="2583:0"><div data-aura-rendered-by="2576:0">
       <a aria-required="false" class="select" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Salutation" title="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="2577:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="45">--None--</a>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="select-options popupTargetContainer uiPopupTarget uiMenuList uiMenuList--default uiMenuList--left uiMenuList--short" data-aura-rendered-by="2595:0" data-aura-class="uiPopupTarget uiMenuList uiMenuList--default uiMenuList--left uiMenuList--short" aria-labelledby="2574:0"><div class="select-options" role="menu" data-aura-rendered-by="2589:0"><!--render facet: 2590:0-->
<ul class="scrollable" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="2591:0" data- scoped-scroll="true"><!--render facet: 2592:0--></ul>
</div></div></div>
```

I want code for locating dropdown icon and select a first value from that.

Comment: I don't see a dropdown

Comment: I don't understand one thing - First there is no drop down and second is even if you are locating element that only contains --None-- and than your selecting index 1,  how can index be 1??

Comment: Its not seems  a dropdown. You have to click one selected element using `click()`  rather then `Select` class

Comment: @metar first i want to locate dropdown icon. i want to select value "Mr." from the dropdown.Please suggest any other measure.

Comment: @abhishek index1 has value of "Mr." from dropdown value. First locate that dropdown icon. Above code i tried. Pls usggest me any other measure.

Comment: @trimantra pls send me code. Above i send full dom structure. I  want to locate and select dropdown icon of Mr. Please suggest any other measure.

Comment: You are using //a[contains(text(),'--None--')] , which will only locate the link that has text = --None--. @SrieedherSanthakumar kindly provide the correct HTML code. We will provide you the code.

Comment: @abhishek  i inspected this is dom structure <div data-aura-rendered-by="5190:0"><a aria-required="false" class="select" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Salutation" title="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="5191:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="79">--None--</a></div>

Comment: @abhishek first i send full dom structure

Comment: @abhishek u want again full dom structure.

Comment: can you share the site URL if possible ?

Comment: @Trimantra  https://login.salesforce.com/

Comment: @Trimantra In that first clicked New contact button . After that i want to select dropdown value of Mr. from that. Pls send line of code to locate dropdown and select value of Mr. I tried these lines of code  WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.className("select"))));
   Select sel = new Select(dropdown);
   sel.selectByValue("Mr."); this is not clicking. Error is Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "a". Please help in that.

Comment: className("select") is not working because there is 4 other element with same classname.                                                       
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("--None--")).click(); //Click on drop down
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@title='Mr.']")));//wait for element visibility
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Mr.']")).click(); click on title mr

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar try above code, it will solve your problem. You can use By.xpath("//a[@class='select'])[2]") also to locate the exact --None-- drop down.

Comment: @abhishek i will try this above code and update you.

Comment: @abhishek. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

Comment: second line driver.findElement(By.linkText("--None--")).click(); third line is wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.‌​xpath("//*[@title='M‌​r.']"))); fourth line is wait for element visibility driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Mr.']")).click(); Third line is giving error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //a[@title = 'M‌​r.']

Comment: @abhishek timed out exception after 20 seconds. It is clicking dropdown icon but it is not clicking value Mr. Please help me on this.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar Can you consider updating us your exact manual steps you want to perform? I din't find any `New contact button` in https://login.salesforce.com/ url. Thanks

Comment: @Debanjan After logging into salesforce application, Click on App launcher symbol at left corner. In that please click contacts . After that new button is visible.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar What are the credentials for logging into salesforce application? Thanks

Comment: @Debanjan , we have to create account first. With that we can login inside. For me , i completed the scenario till last. But it is not logging out. I tried below code : 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class = profileTrigger']")).click();
     JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  /*exe1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newbt);*/
     jse.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)");

Comment: u want dom structure for that?